# Store 30 days of MySQLDump using shell

Tags: shell

I would like to have a daily backup of a MySQL database (on another server). To do with I had the intention of adding the day to the dump file name so it will rewrite monthly but there is a key issue. I have no idea about shell, nor do I have access to a test environment to dabble.

The code I've create is

```
#!/bin/bash
 CURR_DAY=`date +"%d"`
 echo "Commencing backup for today $CURR_DAY"
 DB_BACKUP="/hsphere/local/home/backup_account/backups/mysql_backups"
 DBUSER="user"
 DB_PASSWD="xxx"
 HN="123.456.789.001"    
 DB="maindb"
 # Create the backup directory
 mkdir -p $DB_BACKUP
 echo "---------------------"
 mysqldump -u $DBUSER -p$DB_PASSWD -h $HN $DB | gzip > $DB_BACKUP/mysqldump_$DB_$CURR_DAY.gz
 echo "---------------------"
```

I appear to be getting a CR or LF in the mySQLDump line where the variables are so what am I doing incorrectly please?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting a CR or LF in the mySQLDump line"?

Comment: Michael, the mysqldump line appears over three lines in the logging email we receive (we are on a hosted server) and the error message appears to show that it is missing part of the commands.

Comment: (FYI, if you start a comment with `@michaelb958` the system notifies me that you're replying to my comment.)

Comment: Try `${DB_BACKUP}/mysqldump_${DB}_${CURR_DAY}.gz`.  The curly braces here delineate the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell script needs some work.

1. Always quote your variable expansions. Unquoted, they will [disappear altogether if empty, and do nasty things if they contain spaces](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target).
2. Don't use backquotes - bash has a perfectly good `$(command)` syntax, which you [really should use instead](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). (Quote these as well.)
3. Watch out when you have variable names mixed with other stuff - the other stuff can look like an extension of the variable name and cause interesting behaviour.

Your script, revisited:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURR_DAY="$(date +%d)"
echo Commencing backup for today "$CURR_DAY"
DB_BACKUP="/hsphere/local/home/backup_account/backups/mysql_backups"
DBUSER=user
DB_PASSWD=xxx
HN=123.456.789.001
DB=maindb

# Create the backup directory
mkdir -p "$DB_BACKUP"
echo ---------------------
mysqldump -u "$DBUSER" -p"$DB_PASSWD" -h "$HN" "$DB" | gzip > "$DB_BACKUP/mysqldump_${DB}_${CURR_DAY}.gz"
echo ---------------------
```

Adding braces in the `mysqldump` line has fixed at least one other bug - the shell tried to interpolate `$DB_`, instead of `$DB` followed by an underscore.

The quoting has a reasonable chance of fixing the random-newlines problem; if it doesn't, comment.